# How to Download a directory on Google Drive using Python?

Tags: python, google-drive-api, drive

```
service = self.auth()
items = self.listFilesInFolder(downLoadFolderKey)
for item in items:
    file_id = (item.get('id'))
    file_name = (item.get('name'))
    request = service.files().get_media(fileId=file_id)
    fh = io.BytesIO()
    downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
    done = False
    while done is False:
        status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
        print ("Download %d%%." % int(status.progress() * 100) + file_name)
    filepath = fileDownPath + file_name
    with io.open(filepath, 'wb') as f:
        fh.seek(0)
        f.write(fh.read())
```

I am using Google Drive API v3.
I am trying to download a full directory. But the problem is the directory itself contains folders and when I try to run this bit of code. This error happens.

```
<HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1ssF0XD8pi6oh6DXB1prIJPWKMz9dggm2?alt=media returned "Only files with binary content can be downloaded. Use Export with Google Docs files.">
```

The error I figure is due to it trying to download the folders, within the directory. But how do I download the full directory?

P.S The directory changes so I cannot hard code file IDs and then download the files.

Comment: From `But the problem is the directory itself contains folders and when I try to run this bit of code.`, about `items`, all files and folders you want to download are included in it? Namely, can your script of `listFilesInFolder` retrieve all files in the specific folder with the subfolders? If you can do that, I think that you can download the files by checking the mimeType. How about this? By the way, on your script, when Google Docs files are included in the file list, such error occurs. So please be careful this.

Comment: Hey @Tanaike! Thats what I ended up doing. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed the modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your situation and that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your situation and goal as follows.

- By `items = self.listFilesInFolder(downLoadFolderKey)`, you have already been able to retrieve all file and folder list including the subfolders under the specific folder.
- `items` include the mimeType for each files and folders.
- In your issue, when the folder is used in the loop, the error occurs.
- You want to remove this error.

For this, how about this answer?

#### Modification point:

- When the mimeType is included in `items` of `items = self.listFilesInFolder(downLoadFolderKey)`, the folder can be checked by the mimeType. The mimeType of folder is `application/vnd.google-apps.folder`.
- From your script, I think that when the Google Docs file (Spreadsheet, Document, Slides and so on) is downloaded with the method of "Files: get", the same error occurs.
- In order to download the Google Docs files, it is required to use the method of "Files: export".

When above point is reflected to your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

From:

```
request = service.files().get_media(fileId=file_id)
```

To:

```
file_mimeType = (item.get('mimeType'))
if file_mimeType == 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder':
    continue
request = service.files().export_media(fileId=file_id, mimeType='application/pdf') if 'application/vnd.google-apps' in file_mimeType else service.files().get_media(fileId=file_id)
```

- In this modification, **at first, please confirm whether the file mimeType to `items` of `items = self.listFilesInFolder(downLoadFolderKey)` is included, again**. By this, the folder can be skipped and also, Google Docs files and the files except for Google Docs can be downloaded using the value of mimeType.
- In this modification, as a sample modification, Google Docs files are downloaded as the PDF file. If you want to change the output mimeType, please modify `mimeType='application/pdf'`.

#### References:

- [G Suite and Drive MIME Types](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/mime-types)
- [Files: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get)
- [Files: export](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export)